# Running an app in background to copy a particular folder from pen drive to a physical device?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app which I want to run it in the background. The project has a basic concept of copying files from ***pen drive to android device*** in **local storage** without app opening and also to copy only a single folder named **thinpc** whenever pen drive is attached to a device it automatically starts copying folder (thinpc) without any permission. I have done the copying part but the issue is that the app is not working automatically I have to do touch that folder to copy which I don't want to do. 
Here is the reference link to complete code and also I am sharing the MainActivity.java

" https://github.com/magnusja/libaums "

MainActivity.java

```
private void discoverDevice() {
    UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    massStorageDevices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this);

    if (massStorageDevices.length == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "no device found!");
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("No Pen drive detected ");
        listView.setAdapter(null);
        return;
    }else {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("thinpc");
    }

  @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
    UsbFile entry = adapter.getItem(position);
    try {
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            dirs.push(adapter.getCurrentDir());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter = new UsbFileListAdapter(this, entry));
        } else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.request_write_storage_perm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_EXT_STORAGE_WRITE_PERM);
                }

                return;
            }

            CopyTaskParam param = new CopyTaskParam();
            param.from = entry;
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/thinpc/cache");
            f.mkdirs();
            int index = entry.getName().lastIndexOf(".") > 0
                    ? entry.getName().lastIndexOf(".")
                    : entry.getName().length();
            String prefix = entry.getName().substring(0, index);
            String ext = entry.getName().substring(index);
            // prefix must be at least 3 characters
            if(prefix.length() < 3) {
                prefix += "pad";
            }
            param.to = File.createTempFile(prefix, ext, f);
            new CopyTask().execute(param);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error staring to copy!", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Activity result is not ok");
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == OPEN_STORAGE_PROVIDER_RESULT) {
        Uri uri;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(uri);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == COPY_STORAGE_PROVIDER_RESULT) {
        Uri uri;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

            CopyToUsbTaskParam params = new CopyToUsbTaskParam();
            params.from = uri;

            new CopyToUsbTask().execute(params);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE_RESULT) {
        Uri uri;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

            CopyToUsbTaskParam params = new CopyToUsbTaskParam();
            params.from = uri;

            new CopyFolderToUsbTask().execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Remaining code is in the reference link above
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question here ? If you want to run a Service in background the only way is `Foreground Service`.

Comment: But how to use it in this particular code I am not getting any solution